# Не могу понять в чем проблема....JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, не работает кнопка `adblock_button_close`, `adBlockDetected` в стилях `display: none`?

```
var adBlockDetected = function() {
    $('.forCenterBlock').css('display', 'block');
}
var adBlockUndetected = function() {
    $('.forCenterBlock').css('display', 'none');
}
if(typeof  FuckAdBlock === 'undefined') {
    $(document).ready(adBlockDetected);
} else {
    fuckAdBlock.on(true, adBlockDetected).on(false, adBlockUndetected);
}
$(".adblock_button_close").click(function(){
    $('.forCenterBlock').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Есть *div* `forCenterBlock`, который изначально `display: none;` (прописано в *css*). При загрузке страницы если `FuckAdBlock === 'undefined'` блоку `forCenterBlock` нужно присвоить `display:block;` в противном случае `display: none;`.

И есть кнопка `adblock_button_close`, которая по клику должна присваивать блоку `forCenterBlock display: none;`

Вот кнопка почему–то не работает)

Comment: `FuckAdBlock` и `fuckAdBlock` - две разные переменные. Должна вываливаться ошибка `fuckAdBlock is undefined`

Comment: Опишите подробнее. Что значит "не работает"? Не исчезает блок `forCenterBlock`? У кого в стилях `display:none`? Почти ничего не понятно.

Comment: 1 - ошибки в консоли? 2 - кнопка `adblock_button_close` присутствует на странице сразу при ее загрузки, или добавляется позже?